# Changing INSTALLDIR through user interaction (msi setup)

Tags: wix

I have created a msi file with wix which lets the user choose a target directory. The installation is correct.

When the user selects a target directory which is not the default, the uninstallation does not remove all the files.

I do NOT use WixUI_InstallDir.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PEFiles">
                <Directory Id="Company" Name="My Company">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="My Product Default">
                        <Directory Id="DOC" Name="Doc">


<Dialog Id="BrowseDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] [Setup]" NoMinimize="yes">
    <Control Id="PathEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="84" Y="202" Width="261" Height="18" Property="_BrowseProperty" Indirect="yes" />
    <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="[ButtonText_OK]">
        <Publish Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[_BrowseProperty]">1</Publish>
        <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
    </Control>
</Dialog>
```

InstallLog:

```
MSI (c) (38:44) [10:03:19:521]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\My Company\My Product Default\'.
MSI (c) (38:3C) [10:03:27:680]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding _BrowseProperty property. Its value is 'INSTALLDIR'.
Action 10:03:27: BrowseDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (38:3C) [10:03:39:099]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLDIR property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files\My Company\My Product Default\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files\My Company\My folder\'.
MSI (c) (38:3C) [10:03:39:209]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying DOC property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files\My Company\My Product Default\Doc\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files\My Company\My folder\Doc\'.
...
```

UninstallLog:

```
MSI (s) (48:6C) [10:22:34:485]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\My Company\My Product Default\'.
MSI (s) (48:6C) [10:22:34:485]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DOC property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\My Company\My Product Default\Doc\'.
```

Other components are installed/uninstalled normally. During uninstall, the path of some components is set to the default path instead of the user-selected path.

How can I fix the uninstallation?

Edit:
I use WIX 3.5.2519.0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't use the dialog during uninstall, the value you choose during installation isn't saved anywhere by the installer. Which means on uninstall it uses all the default values.

One way to get around this is to save the users choice in a registry key during installation then read that key during the uninstall.